# two column html table with group

Tags: javascript, html

I expect `next to name` column is besides iphone, why my table doesn't work as expected?

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <tr>
          <td>Name:</td>
          <td>iphone</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Price:</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Qty</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
      </td>

      <td>next to name:</td>
      <td>12345</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It's work correctly, can you explain better what would you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write `tr` inside of `td`. You can add `table` wrapper for the `<tr>`

```html
<table border='1'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Name:</td>
          <td>iphone</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Price:</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Qty</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>next to name:</td>
      <td>12345</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```